# Geoman event pm:create doesn't fire when adding layers programmatically

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-geoman

I'm using `react-leaflet` with the Geoman plugin, and I notice that `pm:create` doesn't fire when I add new layers programmatically. This code runs on startup and again anytime the `activeFeatureGroup` is changed:

```js
map.pm.setGlobalOptions({
  ...map.pm.getGlobalOptions(),
  layerGroup: activeFeatureGroup,
  hintlineStyle: { color },
  templineStyle: { color },
})
```

This is my function to programmatically add new layers from GeoJSON:

```js
const opts = { style: { color } }
geoJSON(newGeoJsonObject, opts).addTo(activeFeatureGroup)
```

How can I get `pm:create` to fire after this code runs? **The main concern is that I'm adding event listeners to every layer that `pm:create` sees, so an alternative solution would be a way to set one listener on the map instance that fires anytime a layer is added in Geoman, but I don't see support for this in the Geoman docs.**

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get pm:create to fire after this code runs?

You can achive this in 3 different ways:

1. Create a function and call it after running the geoJson part and in the `pm:create` listener
2. add a listener on the map `layeradd` (leaflet event) and run the same code as in `pm:create`
3. you can fire `pm:create` manually with `map.fire('pm:create',{layer: XYZ});` (I don't recommand this!)

> alternative solution would be a way to set one listener on the map instance that fires anytime a layer is added in Geoman

This is `pm:create` ... if you mean to fire an event for each layer that is intialized and is added to Geoman, you can achive this by listening on `layeradd` and then check if the Geoman property `layer.pm` exists.